# I can't get the right side of my RichFaces pickList populated

Tags: richfaces

I've read plenty on how I should do this, but I can't seem to get it working.  The left side populates fine.  I'm just dealing with Strings.  I'm using RichFaces 3.3.3 and JSF 1.2.
Thanks.

Here's my bean for the right side:

```
public List<String> getTestRightSide(){
        List<String> selectItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        selectItems.add("OH");

        return selectItems;
    }

    public void setTestRightSide(){

    }
```

The left side is being populated by a list of SelectItems defined as follows and they display fine.

```
SelectItem item = new SelectItem(int, String, String);
```

Here's my JSF:

```
<rich:pickList showButtonsLabel="false" value="#{selectBean.testRightSide}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectBean.allGeographySelectItems}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Nothing gets populated in the right.  I can move things around fine.
A subquestion... the selectBean .testRightSide is where the items get sent to upon submission, right?

Comment: I found the answer.  What I put in the right list must be a subset of what's contained in the left list.
My right list was not a subset of the left list.  So I also added everything I was trying to put in the right list to left list and all is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. What I put in the right list must be a subset of what's contained in the left list. My right list was not a subset of the left list. So I also added everything I was trying to put in the right list to left list and all is good.